# Django user HiddenInput vs. saving directly in views with Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Please this as a consideration question. Maybe somebody will use one of the 
solutions below.

I have a couple of models which contain a `ForeignKey(User)` field.
My class-based create views are derived from the generic `CreateView`.

There are two options to save the associated user when adding a new object:

1. Saving the form in the views by overriding the `form_valid` method;
   this doesn't expose `user_id` (and other not mentioned here data that should not be exposed)

   ```
   class CreateOfferView(CreateView):

       model = Offer
       form_class = SomeModelFormWithUserFieldExcluded

       def form_valid(self, form):
           instance = form.save(commit=False)
           instance.user = self.request.user
           instance.save()
   ```
2. Saving the form with user id stored (and exposed) in a hidden field.
   Here's the tricky part. There are more models with user field... so 
   when creating a form I need to fill the user field with initial (currently logged in) user and also I need to make that field hidden. For this purpose I've used my `OwnFormMixin`

   ```
   class OwnFormMixin(object):

       def get_form(self, form_class):
           form = super(OwnFormMixin, self).get_form(form_class)
           form.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

       def get_initial(self):
           initial = super(OwnFormMixin, self).get_initial()
           initial['user'] = self.request.user.pk
           #I could also do this in get_form() with form.fields['user'].initial

   class CreateOfferView(OwnFormMixin, CreateView):
       model = Offer
       form_class = SomeModelFormWithAllFields
   ```

There are more `CreateXXXView` using the `OwnFormMixin`..

How do you save your user data in the forms?

Hidden vs. saving directly in your views? What are pros/cons?

Comment: Why don't you use request.user on validation? Is there a possibility to answer POST a from another user? Why even expose any related to django User data into form or any visible part. It's a potential vulnerability...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're allowing users to *modify* that `ForeignKeyField`, there's no reason to include it in a form — I'd go with your first solution of using `exclude` to keep the user field out of your `ModelForm`, and setting the user from `request.user`. In fact, the [Django documentation now has an example along these exact lines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

You have the advantage of not having to secure against manipulation of the `user_id` parameter, not exposing your internal user IDs and not having to worry about the different Create *vs.* Update cases. A slight disadvantage is that if you ever need the ability to change an object's associated `User` you'll need to start again.